# Grouping by a factor, return 1 if characters match on any row - R

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset is grouped by RunID with a different row for every diagnosis the patient has.

I'm trying to create a new variable for if a particular diagnosis (e.g. pneumonia) appears on any row within that RunID.

I tried using any but received the error message
`` Caused by warning in `any()`: ! coercing argument of type 'character' to logical ``

Any suggestions on how to fix it?  What I tried was:

```
data %>%
  group_by(RunID) %>%
  mutate(Pneumonia = ifelse(any(diagnosis="Pneumonia"),1,0))
```

reprex:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

data <- tribble(
  ~RunID, ~diagnosis,
  "A12", "Pneumonia",
  "A12", NA,
  "A12", "copd",
  "A12", "CF",
)

data$RunID<-as.factor(data$RunID)

desired <- tribble(
  ~RunID, ~diagnosis, ~Pneumonia,
  "A12", "Pneumonia", 1,
  "A12", NA, 1,
  "A12", "copd", 1,
  "A12", "CF", 1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need `==` instead of `=` in `any(diagnosis="Pneumonia")` but, it can be also done as

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
data %>% 
  mutate(pneumonia = +('Pneumonia' %in% diagnosis), .by = 'RunID')
```

Comment: that worked perfectly thank you!  What is the + in front of the parentheses?  I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @jpryan28 logical TRUE/FALSE (from `%in%`) is coerced to 1/0 with `+` or `as.integer`, thus avoiding the use of `ifelse`